# How to find hydrogen wave-functions?

Tags: wavefunction, hydrogen, orbitals

I have found the hydrogen wave functions and would now like to calculate the function that describes the orbitals so that I can plot this function and see how they look.

I don't know how I can do that and it is crazy how I cannot find anything on the subject on the internet as if there was no relation between the wave functions and the orbitals.

Could you please tell me what I need to do to get a function $r(\theta,\phi)$ out of my wave functions $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$.

Comment: Pretty much any textbook in quantum mechanics will show how to derive $\Psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)$. There's also plenty of material online that does it, [here](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/EE222./asset/Lesson_21_The_hydrogen_atom_solutions.pdf) is one example

Comment: There is no unique way to do that. The images you have seen are visualizations, and that means that someone made a decision about what the plot was to mean. What do you want yours to mean. (But be prepared to have that choice criticized.)

Comment: I already have derived them, I have a list of them with me. What I want is the polar equation of the corresponding orbitals.

Comment: @dmckee Well I thought I'd chose the shapes so that the probability of finding an electron in each of them was given by a fixed number like 90% for example.

Comment: Are you imagining something like reproducing [this table](http://www.orbitals.com/orb/index.html)?

Comment: @rob Exactly, I would like to graph those. But I can only see the pictures and not the polar equation that descibes them.

Comment: The page that I linked is written by the author of some abandonware whose documentation may be interesting for you to read. As others have said: it's a nontrivial problem, and there are several choices that you have to make.

Answer (score 4):

When you say

> I already have derived them, I have a list of them with me. What I want is the polar equation of the corresponding orbitals.

I take it you have the wavefunctions
$$
 \psi _{n\ell m}(r,\theta ,\varphi )
={\sqrt {{\left({\frac {2}{na_{0}}}\right)}^{3}{\frac {(n-\ell -1)!}{2n(n+\ell )!}}}}
e^{-r /na_0}
 \left(\frac{2r}{na_0}\right)^{\ell }
L_{n-\ell -1}^{2\ell +1}\mathopen{}\left(\frac{2r}{na_0}\right)\mathclose{}
Y_{\ell }^{m}(\theta ,\varphi )
$$
as derived e.g. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction), and you're looking for a representation of the form $r=f(\theta,\varphi)$.

This is not doable in a unique way: different authors choose different ways to graphically present the behaviour of $\psi _{n\ell m}(r,\theta ,\varphi )$, and different choices give different representations.

Usually, however, the most useful graphical representation is **not** in an equation of the form $r=f(\theta,\varphi)$, but rather you plot the surfaces of constant $|\psi _{n\ell m}|^2$, setting the level to some (arbitrary!) probability that will make for a pretty picture. Depending on what you're after, it can be a good idea to take the real or imaginary parts of $\psi _{n\ell m}$ before making the contour plot, which will switch the azimuthal harmonic from $e^{im\varphi}$ to sines and cosines, and thereby bring in more information into the plot.